# Can we configure Kendo grid data source to be Synchronous

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can we configure Kendo grid data source to be Synchronous

```
  .DataSource(dataSource =>
           dataSource.Ajax()

  .Model(model =>
    {
  .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home")))
  .......


  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Is this is an Ajax Asynchronous call. If so can we make this call to a Synchronous call.
Please suggest me a solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

To force the Kendo datasource for synchronous behavior, configure your datasource transport  with async: false e.g.

```
    var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                async: false,
                url: function (data) {
                    return "/odata/Product";
                },
                dataType: "json"
            },
        },
    });
```

Comment: This works great! The only issue is browser consoles now warn about this feature being deprecated. I'd like my code to still work if this feature is eventually removed. Is there a way to use it with the newer await/async keywords to appease the newer browsers?